# Having trouble using the fetchone method in python

Tags: python

This is the error I have tried fixing this plenty and find myself stuck

```
    total = cur.fetchone()[2]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

```
import sqlite3

def display_records(results):
    for row in results:
        print(row[0], row[1], row[2])
    print()



def display_total(total):
    for row in total:
        print(row[2])
    print()



conn = sqlite3.connect('cities.db')

cur = conn.cursor()


x = int(input('Please select a choice by entering the corresponding number: '))


if x == 1:
    print('Displaying a list of cities sorted by population, in ascending order.')
    cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM Cities ORDER BY Population''')
    results = cur.fetchall()
    display_records(results)


elif x == 2:
    print('Displaying a list of cities sorted by population, in descending order.')
    cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM Cities ORDER BY Population DESC''')
    results = cur.fetchall()
    display_records(results)

elif x == 3:
    print('Displaying a list of cities sorted by name.')
    cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM Cities ORDER BY CityName''')
    results = cur.fetchall()
    display_records(results)

elif x == 4:
    print('Displaying the total population of all cities.')
    cur.execute('''SELECT sum(Population) FROM Cities''')
    total = cur.fetchone()[2]

elif x == 5:
    print('Displaying the average population of all cities.')
    cur.execute('''SELECT AVG(Population) FROM Cities''')
    avg = cur.fetchone()[2]
    print('The total population is:', format(avg, '.2f'))







conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

Im trying to write a program that takes information from a database file. Im however having trouble using the fetchone method to fetch the population data and finding the sum. It would be great if someone could shoot me some pointers.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the returned tuple from cur.fetchone() does not have a third element. This is because the SQL statement (for x==4) only asks for a single parameter, namely `sum(Population)`.

Hence the row returned by fetchone() only consists of a tuple with a single element. To get rid of the error, you should index the first element, not the third. Same goes for x == 5.

```
#[...]
elif x == 4:
    print('Displaying the total population of all cities.')
    cur.execute('''SELECT sum(Population) FROM Cities''')
    total = cur.fetchone()[0]  # <= index the first element

elif x == 5:
    print('Displaying the average population of all cities.')
    cur.execute('''SELECT AVG(Population) FROM Cities''')
    avg = cur.fetchone()[0]  # <= index the first element
    print('The total population is:', format(avg, '.2f'))
```

P.S.: You should do something with the total, e.g. print it. At the moment, it just gets discarded.